# using posts per page = 1 on the same page not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using custom post type twice on the same page and one of them isn't showing unless I set it to -1 `'posts_per_page' => -1`

Here's the full code

```
        <?php
        $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'post_type' => 'add-events', 
        'order' => 'asc' )); 
        ?>
        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php  if( get_field('event_type') == 'Workgroup' ) { ?>
        <div class="workgroup-upcoming-events">
            <?php 
                $date_string = get_field('date');
                $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j, Y', $date_string);
            ?>
            <p class="date-stamp"> <?php echo $date->format('j F'); ?></p><p> Racial Equity and Disparities meeting </p>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>

        <?php
        $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'post_type' => 'add-events', 
        'order' => 'asc' )); 
        ?>
          <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php  if( get_field('event_type') == 'Steering Committee' ) { ?>
        <div class="committee-upcoming-events">
            <?php 
                $date_string = get_field('date');
                $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j, Y', $date_string);
            ?>
            <p class="date-stamp"> <?php echo $date->format('j F'); ?></p><p> Steering Committee meeting
 </p>
        </div>
             <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The goal is to show the first post of Steering Committee or Workgroup.
The code works when I set posts_per_page to -1.

Comment: The `posts_per_page` parameter effectively applies an SQL `LIMIT` to the query. When you pass `1` you are saying to the database, "give me a maximum of one posts", all of which happens before and independent of your loop. The `-1` says "give me everything, I’ll figure it out on my own". Regardless, I’d add a [meta query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/) which should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'post_type' => 'add-events', 
    'order' => 'asc' )); 
    ?>
    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php  if( get_field('event_type') == 'Workgroup' ) : ?>
            <div class="workgroup-upcoming-events">
                <?php 
                $date_string = get_field('date');
                $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j, Y', $date_string);
                ?>
                <p class="date-stamp"> <?php echo $date->format('j F'); ?></p><p> Racial Equity and Disparities meeting </p>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php  if( get_field('event_type') == 'Steering Committee' ) : ?>
                <div class="committee-upcoming-events">
                    <?php 
                    $date_string = get_field('date');
                    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j, Y', $date_string);
                    ?>
                    <p class="date-stamp"> <?php echo $date->format('j F'); ?></p><p> Steering Committee meeting
                    </p>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```